# Confirming when PHP's `file_put_contents()` is complete

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

In my Laravel app, I'm using streaming to download large files (> 1GB) to my server for additional processing:

```
    $stream = Storage::disk('google')->getDriver()->readStream($file['path']);
    file_put_contents(public_path("files/{$filename}.tiff"), stream_get_contents($stream));

    if (file_exists(public_path("files/{$filename}.tiff"))) {
        ConvertTIFF::dispatch();
        return;
    }
```

The problem is that, because I'm streaming the file, the file itself gets created long before the streaming process is actually complete. So my `file_exists()` check will frequently fire my `ConvertTIFF` event before the file is complete.

Is there a simpler way to check that the `file_put_contents()` streaming process is complete? Or is there a way to make the process blocking, so there's no danger of the event before fired before the file is fully downloaded?

Comment: You may want to consider a worker based approach for this, honestly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`file_put_contents()`returns the number of bytes that were written to the file and False if not success. So you can check the status like this

```
$status = file_put_contents(public_path("files/{$filename}.tiff"), stream_get_contents($stream));

/*if ($status) {
    echo "success";
} else {
    echo "failed";
}*/

return $status;
```